# Font awesome icons not showing up in ASP.NET CORE MVC Project

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, font-awesome

I'm working on an ASP.NET CORE MVC application and i'm having trouble loading the font awesome icons. Here is what the folder layout is:[image]

Here is what my _layout.cshtml looks like:

```
<environment include="Development">
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/font-awesome/css/fontawesome.css" />
</environment>
<environment exclude="Development">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"
        asp-fallback-src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
        asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery"
        crossorigin="anonymous"
        integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=">
</script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        asp-fallback-src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery && window.jQuery.fn && window.jQuery.fn.modal"
        crossorigin="anonymous"
        integrity="sha384-xrRywqdh3PHs8keKZN+8zzc5TX0GRTLCcmivcbNJWm2rs5C8PRhcEn3czEjhAO9o">
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/font-awesome/css/fontawesome.min.css" />
</environment>
<script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>

@RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
```

Here's how i'm trying to use the fontawesome icons:

```
  <span class='input-group date datepicker'>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CandidateDetail.DateOfBirth, new { @id = "DateOfBirth", @class = "form-control" })
                    <span class="input-group-append">
                        <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-calendar"></i></span>
                    </span>
                </span>
```

All i'm seeing when i launch the project is a square. Anything i'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Which version of Font awesome are you using?

Comment: @JSON the latest one, above Version 5

Comment: Are there any error in your console ?

Comment: @TonyNgo nope, no errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the console+network tab on chrome developer tools (f12)

If you hosted application on local IIS, most of the time IIS doesn't allow mime type **.woff** by default. you can add mime type using **web.config**

```
<system.webServer>
  <staticContent>
    <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="font/woff2" />
  </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

Another reason would be the relative path between CSS files and font files not matching.
since you are using the same directory structure provided with the FontAwesome, I don't
think this would be the problem.

Comment: This was the answer.

Answer (score 21):

For referencing `font-awesome`, you should add `~/lib/font-awesome/css/all.css` instead of `~/lib/font-awesome/css/fontawesome.css`.

Add code below to `<environment include="Development">`

```
<environment include="Development">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link href="~/lib/font-awesome/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</environment>
```

Comment: This was part of the solution.

Comment: Worked for me when hosting on Kestrel

Comment: Not exactly what you did, but this put me on the right track to the solution. I upgraded from 4.x to 5.x, and one of the new icons was not showing. I simply had to update the href from ```<link href="/Content/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />``` to ```<link href="/Content/fontawesome-all.css" rel="stylesheet" />``` in my _Layout.cshtml.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have had the css file in the bundle in my App MVC ASP.net 4.8:

```html
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
          "~/css/sb-admin-2.min.css",
          "~/vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css",
          "~/vendor/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css",
            "~/Content/jquery-ui.css",
           "~/Content/font/bootstrap-icons.min.css" 
          ));
```

In my local environment, it works; however, it was not working in the Azure Web Application. To fix it, I decided to remove it from the bundle section and add it directly to the HEAD section in my _layout.cshtml.

```html
<head>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css">
</head>
```